# Force close when taping on a marker

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have this code to show an AlertDialog when taping on a marker:

```
public void showOverlay (OverlayItem overlay)
        {
        db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String[] columns_descri = new String[] {COL_DESCRI};

        Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, columns_descri,null, null, null, null, null, null);

        String description = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_DESCRI));
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Geo.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Infos.");
        dialog.setMessage(description);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {    
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
        db.close();


    }

        @Override
        public boolean onTap(int index)

        {
 showOverlay(getItem(index)) ;
 return super.onTap(index) ;
 }
```

The strange thing that i have a FC with a logcat error:

```
08-24 20:51:42.466: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(265): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-24 20:51:42.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(265): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 4
```

Any idea please?
Thank you.

Comment: question is related to (or mostly equal): [CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException problem:Index 4 requested, with a size of 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165227/cursorindexoutofboundsexception-problemind?ex-4-requested-with-a-size-of-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the cursor is first created, it's index is at -1 (before the beginning of the list).  You need to call `cur.moveToFirst()` before you attempt to retrieve any data from it.  `moveToFirst()` will also return false if the cursor is empty, which could be useful:

```
public void showOverlay (OverlayItem overlay, int index)
{
   db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

   String[] columns_descri = new String[] {COL_DESCRI};

   Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, columns_descri,null, null, null, null, null, null);

   if (cur.moveToPosition(index)) {
         String description = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_DESCRI));
         AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Geo.this);
         dialog.setTitle("Infos.");
         dialog.setMessage(description);
         dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {    
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 dialog.dismiss();
             }
         });
         dialog.show();
   }
   else {
        //ERROR!  cursor is empty, throw a toast or something
   }

   db.close();
}
```

Comment: I edited my code with the proposed solution, but i have 4 alertdialogs shown with the same description. I think it's just reading the first index and showing it as many i have entries in the "Description" column, in my case, 4. Any other idea please?

Comment: Keep an index of where you are and use `cur.moveToPosition()` instead.  Or, you could call `cur.moveToNext()` after each use.  I'll update the code with the `moveToNext()` code.

Comment: the code will only work if you want to show the 4 different dialogs in a row, but if you want to show a specific dialog, you should either run a better, more distinct query or else pass in the index of the row you want to use for the dialog as a parameter to `moveToPosition()`.  If the problem is that your code is showing 4 alert dialogs, instead of just 1, then the error is not within the posted code and is coming from somewhere else.  I'm not fully sure what you mean in your comment though.

Comment: I'm changing the code to show how you would use the function by passing in an index and using `moveToPosition()`.

Comment: :( Oh my god, I did exactly what you told me, and same problem. I explain: when i tap to just one marker, i have 6 alertdialogs shown at the same time with the same description. Don't know why, it's not on a loop :\

Comment: what do you mean by tap on a marker?  If possible, please update your question with more detail on what you're trying to do.  The code above seems fine, so my guess is that the issue is elsewhere in your code.  In any case, the popping up of 6 dialogs is a separate issue from this question, so I'd consider posting another question with your problem.